# Travando campo dentro em Div Oculta

Tags: javascript

Como desabilitar um campo que esteja dentro de uma div oculta para não funcionar no envio do formulário

Exemp: nesse meu script a baixo ao enviar o formulario tambem é enviado os campos que estão ocultos, mais esse campos só devem ser enviados quando ficam a mostra

como corrigir isso?

```js
  function Mudarestado(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "block")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
 <form action="teste.php" method="GET">  
 Habilitar
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')" class="valores" name="choice" value="200" /><br/>
<br><br>
Campo 1 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" />
         <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" />
 <br><br>
 <div id="minhaDiv" style="display: none;">
Campo 2 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" />
         <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" />

 </div>
      
      
 <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
    
 </form>
```

Comment: Você vai usa-los novamente? se não basta retira-los em vez de ocultar

Comment: Ola... Sim vou usa-lo de acordo com a necessidade  o checkbox é para isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode percorrer todos os elementos filhos de sua `div` e desabilitar/habilitar dependendo de sua necessidade.

Abaixo eu fiz um exemplo, com o `for()` redundante, apenas para exemplificar o que estou falando.

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  var elements = document.getElementById(el).children;
  if (display == "block") {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].disabled = true;
      console.log(elements[i]);
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].disabled = false;
      console.log(elements[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="teste.php" method="GET">
  Habilitar
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')" class="valores" name="choice" value="200" /><br/>
  <br><br> Campo 1 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" />
  <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" />
  <br><br>
  <div id="minhaDiv" style="display: none;">
    Campo 2 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" disabled/>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" disabled/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
</form>
```

Veja que em `var elements = document.getElementById(el).children;` eu consigo todos os elementos que estão dentro de `minhaDiv`. Com isso, não fiz separação se é um `input` ou algum outro elemento, pois creio que você deseja desabilitar todos. Mas, você pode fazer tal verificação caso queira.

Comment: Amigo mesmo desabilitado continua passando pro GET Olha teste.php?id=Ola&id=Ola2&id=Ola&id=Ola2

Comment: @FabioHenrique Você clicou em habilitar 2x? Pergunto isso pq os `inputs` não começam com `disabled`. Editei a resposta com esse detalhe, assim ao clicar em `entrar` de início os valores já estarão desabilitados.

Comment: Perfeito Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "block"){
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
            //Desabilita todos os inputs de dentro da div
            $('#minhaDiv :input').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
            //Habilita todos os inputs de dentro da div
            $('#minhaDiv :input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="teste.php" method="GET">  
 Habilitar
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')" class="valores" name="choice" value="200" /><br/>
<br><br>
Campo 1 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" />
         <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" />
 <br><br>
 <div id="minhaDiv" style="display: none;">
Campo 2 :<input type="text" name="id" value="Ola" disabled />
         <input type="text" name="id" value="Ola2" disabled />

 </div>
      
      
 <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
    
 </form>
```

Observe que mantive o seu código praticamente como estava, apenas adicionei duas linhas, uma dentro do `if` para desativar os campos em questão quando desmarcar o `checkbox` e outra dentro do `else` para ativar os campos ao marcar o `checkbox` novamente.
Obs.: Não esqueça de importar a biblioteca `jQuery` do `JavaScript`, conforme primeira linha do segundo bloco de código.

Comment: Amigo mesmo desabilitado continua passando pro GET  Olha teste.php?id=Ola&id=Ola2&id=Ola&id=Ola2

Comment: @FabioHenrique Editei a resposta, tente novamente.